# How to verify "no-cache" behavior in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, cache-control

I think my server doesn't honor the "Cache-control: no-cache" request header, which by definition orders browser to first check up on server for file verification before returning it from cache. Server returns "Cache-control: max-age=315360000, public" which is 10 years.

The question is: how can I check if the browser does that verification request? I use the latest Chrome 69 developer tools and I see this:

Network panel line[image]

Request headers[image]

Response headers[image]

I assume this means file has not been verified and no requests has been sent, because of the response header. Can anyone help me understanding how the network panel entry should look like when the file is returned from cache but browser has previously checked for the file on server?